# Adding express-session middleware crashes with "ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined"

Tags: node.js, session, express

I have a Node application.  When I try to add session middleware

```
app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 50000000 }}));
```

without making any further changes, my application crashes when any route reaches a `res.send` with the following error:

```
ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined
    at MemoryStore.set (/node_modules/express-session/session/memory.js:71:3)
    at Session.save (/node_modules/express-session/session/session.js:63:25)
    at ServerResponse.res.end (/node_modules/express-session/index.js:303:19)
    at ServerResponse.res.send (/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:150:8)
    at ServerResponse.res.json (/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:191:15)
    at ServerResponse.res.send (/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:118:21)
```

I'm using `"express": "~4.0.0"`, `"express-session": "~1.0.0"`, and `"cookie-parser": "~1.0.0"`

What causes this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: What version of node do you have installed (`node -v`) ?

Comment: v0.8.2 -_- I don't know why I assumed I had >= v0.10. Still possibly worth the answer since it's not on Stack yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the MemoryStore, you need to use node v0.10+ since setImmediate was introduced in v0.10.

Update: This was considered a bug in Express 4.x. Express 4.1.1 [updates](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/commit/c0545813706ffa17161293af00fe39b7f2f43fe2) package.json to reflect compatibility with Node v.10 or later.

Comment: FWIW I've created an [issue](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/30) about this on the express-session repo.